# Change many to many polymorphics association to one to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

User and campaign has many to many association with occupation.I want to change occupation association with user many to one. How I modify it?

User

```
has_many :common_occupations, :as => :profession
has_many :occupations, :through => :common_occupations
```

Occupation

```
class Occupation < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :users, :through => :common_occupations, :source => :profession, :source_type => "User"
has_many :campaigns, :through => :common_occupations, :source => :profession, :source_type => "Campaign"
has_many :common_occupations
```

Campaign

```
has_many :common_occupations, :as => :profession
has_many :occupations, :through => :common_occupations
```

CommonOccupation

```
belongs_to :occupation
belongs_to :profession, :polymorphic => true
```

Answer (score 1):

User

```
has_many :common_occupations, :as => :profession
belongs_to :occupation
```

Occupation

```
has_many :users
has_many :campaigns, :through => :common_occupations, :source => :profession, :source_type => "Campaign"
has_many :common_occupations
```

Campaign

```
has_many :common_occupations, :as => :profession
has_one :occupation, :through => :common_occupations
```

CommonOccupation

```
belongs_to :occupation
belongs_to :profession, :polymorphic => true
```

Moreover you would have to add `occupation_id` column to `users` table.

Also, after that you could remove profession polymorphic association as it will be no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to use `has_one` instead of `has_many`:

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_one :common_occupation, :as => :profession
  has_one :occupation, :through => :common_occupation
```